# Approximate 99th Percentile of dataset

Tags: statistics

So I got a huge set of randomly distributed data. I want to find the 99th percentile.

The data changes everyday, so far I am sorting my data which is taking a long time everyday cause the data is huge. For example if I had numbers 1 to 100 as my data, the 99th percentile would be 99 after sorting.

So If I have 1000 data, each day I replace 20 of them with new data and I would have to recalculate 99 percentile. Notice there is 980 data that are shared. I am wondering, is there a way to approximate the 99 percentile from median, standard deviation and etc?

Comment: Would it be possible to use an online algorithm? ie, every time you get a new data point, just automatically put it into the correct position in the list, rather than sorting post facto? Also, something you might consider is keeping separately the old data and the new, only sort the new data, then merge the two sorted lists- that should be substantially faster.

Comment: The data is really big and I am forced to use MySQL. but the sorting of the data takes hours, that's why I am trying to use other approach to approximate the percentiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both offered answers do not improve on the main bottleneck, which is the $O(n\log n)$ sorting running time (for an array of size $n$).

One can use a clever selection algorithm, which partially sorts the data, to avoid the full sort, and end up with a linear-time computation.

Most of the time this is used to compute the median, which is the 50-th percentile, but can be used for arbitrary selection. This makes heavy use of the main routine behind QuickSort and hence is called the [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). Here is the [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) for the full discussion of the field.

Comment: I was about to suggest migrating this to the CS site because this is more a question about optimal CS procedures than about statistics (or even statistical packages). But your answer (+1) seems right to the point.

Comment: @BruceET thanks. IMO, this site is not a worse place to ask about mathematical properties of algorithms than the CS one...

Answer (score 1):

Can you make any distributional assumptions on the data? If you can assume they're normally distributed, I believe you could approximate the 99th percentile with $\bar x + 2.33*\bar s$ where $\bar x$ is your sample mean and $\bar s$ is the standard deviation of your data. Though whatever software you're using probably has a function similar to `quantile` in `R` that shouldn't take too long to run.

Here's an example using 10,000 random normal draws - the actual 99th percentile is 27.01624 and the approximate is 26.97335

```
set.seed(123)

mu=20
sigma=3

sample <- rnorm(10000,mu,sigma)

#Actual 99th percentile
quantile(sample,0.99)

#Approximate
xbar <- mean(sample)
sbar <- sqrt(var(sample))
xbar + 2.33*sbar
```

Comment: Nice idea. (+1) But I'm wondering how much time would be saved (over finding 99th percentile) if one has to find mean and SD. Certainly some, I'd say.

Comment: @BruceET actually, none. Finding any percentile is a linear-time operation if implemented most efficiently

Comment: @gt6989b: You're right. I was still thinking in the framework of the Question in which the issue is framed as sorting (not really necessary to find 99th percentile).

Comment: @LaughingDay: **skew** not _screw_.

Comment: @BruceET that occurred to me while I was writing the answer. I don't have a good grasp on what occurs under the hood to sort data while I figured the mean/sd could be done in place and might be faster.

Comment: @LaughingDay if you can't make any distributional assumptions then perhaps Micah's suggestion to sort the new data and interweave it into the existing data. Maybe ask over on Stack Overflow? I'm sure there are plenty of MySQL wizards who might be able to help

Comment: Hi thanks BruceET for catching that... I am so sorry, and Craig I did ask on overflow already, they say there is no good way of dealing with it in MySQL, thats why I am trying to optimize the sorting using mathematical method. Anyway, I really appreciate the help guys, I just found something interesting in my text book, I might use frequency table to approximate percentile.

Comment: @gt6989b hi, can you please elaborate on how to find any percentile using linear-time operation? Thanks!

Comment: @LaughingDay yes, you are looking for linear selection algo, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

First, if sorting takes a long time, the process may be inefficient.
Interleaving the new observations with the remaining old ones ought
to be a lot faster than sorting afresh. Also, I suppose 1000 was just
an example, but sorting 1000 observations should be almost instantaneous
with modern hardware and software.

*Note:* Using R on an old computer, I just sorted a million randomly
generated observations from standard normal, and the elapsed time was
almost too short to measure accurately. Maybe this is not a 'real life'
problem as you imply in your Question, but an exercise from an out-dated
textbook.

Second, if the max of the new 20 observations is about the same as
as the 99th percentile of yesterday's 1000, then today's 99 percentile
shouldn't be much different. Also, checking to see how many of today's
large number of observations exceed yesterday's 99th percentile should be quicker
than re-sorting. As a practical matter, you could try in out in practice, but
you might get by with sorting the big dataset every several days.

Comment: Hi, 1000 is just an example. real data is more than 10 billions.

Comment: Then it is certainly worthwhile to use a more efficient way (than sorting) of finding the 99th percentile. See comment by @gt6989 to another Answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your range of values is fixed say from 0 to 100. Maintain list of size 101, and while going through dataset update value count in list and maintain total count. Calculate 1% of total count. Start from bottom of list keep going up cumulating values count till you reach you 1%. And there you have 99 percentile.
Complexity of going through list would be O(n). Finding 99 percentile would take fixed set of iteration, complexity there would be O(1).